# Python: removing an item from a list in the if statement condition?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have this code:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if (myList.remove(4)):
    print "We removed 4, so this is true!"

print myList
```

When I run it, this is what I get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

So it appears that the "4" was removed from the list as specified in the condition of the if statement, yet the if statement did not end up being "True" since the print statement did not print to the console. Why is it that the if statement is false?

Comment: The return value of `list.remove` is `None`

Comment: You're probably looking for `if 4 in myList: myList.remove(4)`

Comment: @c2huc2hu you are the only one who gave a fix to the issue at hand thanks

Answer (score 8):

`myList.remove(4)` does ***not*** return `True` or `False` depending on whether the `remove` operation was successful or not.

Instead, it returns nothing (i.e. `None`) if *successful* and raises a `ValueError` otherwise.

Thus,

```
if mylist.remove(4):
```

translates to

```
if None:
```

which is `False`

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

> list.remove(x)
>   Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x. It is an error if there is no such item.

So `.remove()` either returns `None` or raises a `ValueError`, hence it equates to `False` in your code. [Here is a link to the relevant docs for further reading](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 1):

Because [`.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), like `del`, it doesn't return anything. So, it implicitly returns `None`, which is evaluates to `False` in a Boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

The remove function doesn't actually return anything. So, the if statement if checking for a value, doesn't get one, which means the if statement results in a false.

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
var1 = myList[3]
if var1:
    print "1 - Got a true expression value"
    print var1

var2 = myList.remove(4) # Nothing returned (var2 = None)
if var2: # if statement fails because var2 is None
    print "2 - Got a true expression value"
    print var2
print myList
```

This will result in the following when the code is executed

```
1 - Got a true expression value
4
[1,2,3,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.remove` method for lists returns `None` when the item was found, and throws an error if not.

Here is one option:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]

try:
  a.remove(4)
  print "we removed 4, so this is true!"
except:
  pass

print(a)
```